# How to make even background widths on nav menu

Tags: css

I currently have a NAV menu with three links that do not span the entire menu bar (which is what I want) What I am having a problem with is making each of the links have the same width and not based on the amount of text in the button.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<header>
     <h1>Matt's Meat</h1>

    <div class="navTop"></div>
    <nav>
        <li><a href="#">Product</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Flavors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cart</a>
        </li>
        <nav>
            <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
h1 {
    font-family:'Quicksand', Palatino, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
.navTop {
    width: 850px;
    height: 4px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #34AADC;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #333333;
}
.breadcrumbs {
    width: 850px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #D7D7D7;
}
nav li a {
    font-family:'Quicksand', Palatino, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 17px 25px 17px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 0px solid #ccc;
}
nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4A4A4A;
}
```

Comment: Yes, a picture would be really helpful, as well as a JSFiddle!

Comment: I am a little unclear but if you give each li a 33% width they should be good. I also don't see the Lis contained inside of a ul or ol.

Comment: Please only share the relevant parts of your code. You could even create a jsFiddle that people can play with. Please try to help those who are trying to help you.

Comment: Your HTML is broken. `li` should only occur in `ul` or `ol`. The closing tag for your `nav` is, well, an opening tag :).

Comment: I am new to StackExchange so I appreciate all the help. I will use your advice next time I ask a question. Also thank you for the HTML fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to give li a width.

for example:

```
nav li{
    width:30%;
}
```

Then to make links fill li, therefore making them same size add:

```
nav li a {    
    width:100%;
    text-align:center; 
}
```

Also wrap li tags with `<ul>` tag. See fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z4vdA/2/

Comment: if using a % width, you may need to add `box-sizing:border-box` to work nicely with padding

Answer (score 0):

You can put a width on the li, but if the text is too long, it will wrap to a second line.

```
nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
}
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/PsMjr/).  You'll have to change your hover styles around in this example, but if fixes the width.

Comment: Also, another option is a min-width if you don't want it to break lines when it's longer?

Comment: That would work, up to a point.  Even on massive screens though, eventually you run out of room.